# Error that I can't locate in my javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

// Registration JavaScript Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#userForm").submit(function(e) {
                    removeFeedback();
                var errors = validateForm();
                if (errors =="") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                                provideFeedback(errors);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
        });

                function validateForm() {
                        var errorFields = new Array();
```

//Check that the required fields have data present code:

```
                if ($('lname').val() == "") {
                    errorFields.push('lname');
                }
                if ($('#fname').val() == "") {
                    errorFields.push('fname');
                }
                if ($('#email').val() == "") {
                    errorFields.push('email');
                }
                if ($('#password1').val() == "") {
                    errorFields.push('password1');
                }
```

//Check passwords match code:

```
if ($('#password2').val() !=$('password1').val()) {
                        errorFields.push('password2');
                    }

                    //Very basic e-mail check, just an @ symbol
                    if (!($('#email').val().indexOf(".") > 2) && ($('#email').val().indexOf("@"))) {
                        errorFields.push('email');
                    }

                    if ($('#phone').val() != "") {
                        var phoneNum = $('#phone').val();
                        phoneNum.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
                    if (phoneNum.length != 11) {
                        errorFields.push("phone");
                    }
                    if (!$('input[name=phonetype]:checked').val()) {
                        errorFields.push("phonetype");
                    }
                }

                    return errorFields;
            }
```

//end function validateForm

//Dreamweaver suggests the error is in the following code on line 59 (the first $ sign line), however I can't seem to find it and anyones help will be much appreciated:

```
        function provideFeedback(incomingErrors) {
                for (var i = 0; i < incomingErrors.length; i++) {
                $("#" + incomingErrors[i]).addClass("errorClass');
                $("#" + incomingErrors[i]) + "Error").
        remooveClass("errorFeedback");
                }
                $("errorDiv").html("Errors encountered");
        }

        function removeFeedback() {
            $("#errorDiv").html("");
            $('input').each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("errorClass");
            });
            $('errorSpan').each(function() {
                $(this).addClass("errorFeedback");
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Have you checked your script *in browser*?

Comment: The syntax highlighting should give you a hint.

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 6):

This line is bad:

```
            $("#" + incomingErrors[i]).addClass("errorClass');
```

You have unmatched quotes.